# Scriptaculous Builder Not Setting Selected Value In FireFox

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous, builder

I am trying to build a select options list and apply a default value to it.  It seems to work in Chrome, but not in Firefox.  My code is:

```
var sel2 = Builder.node('select',{
  name: 'type_' + tId,
  id: 'type_' + tId
});
$A(templateTypes).each(function(t,idx){
  var o = Builder.node('option',{value:dataID},DataName);
  sel2.appendChild(o);
  if (curID == dataID) {
    $(sel2).selectedIndex = idx;
  }
});
```

I tried things like:

```
if (curID == dataID) {
  var o = Builder.node('option',{value:dataID,selected:'selected'},DataName);
}
```

That even though set selected="selected" in Firebug, it didn't apply to what was shown.  Hard refreshing doesn't appear to solve it either.

Does someone have a solution that will work across all browsers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems adding a new node to the select box confuses Firefox.  How about this instead:

```
var sel2 = Builder.node('select',{
  name: 'type_' + tId,
  id: 'type_' + tId
});

// store the desired index in this
var selectedIndex = 0;

$A(templateTypes).each(function(t,idx){
  var o = Builder.node('option',{value:dataID},DataName);
  sel2.appendChild(o);
  if (curID == dataID) {
    selectedIndex = idx;
  }
});

// now set the selected index _after_ we've added all the options:
sel2.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
```

Seems to work in my brief test.